# How to place the Radio Button to center of it's background image in Android?

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to run an Android code , where i want to place my radio button into center of his background image. In my code the radio button comes at the left side of the image , i don't understand how to keep it in center.

**Java Code**

```
RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(activity.getApplicationContext());

rdbtn.setButtonDrawable(null);

rdbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radio2);

rdbtn.setId(1);
```

[image]

**Radio2.png**

This is the above image , i want to keep it in the center. please let me know , how can i place the blue checked symbol into the center of the Circle.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

create RelativeLayout put the image inside then place the RadionButton in the middle of the RelativeLayout.

```
View positiveButton = findViewById(R.id.positiveButton);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
positiveButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

this doesnt work for u?

Comment: No friend , i tried but the result is same. I have also tried to make it's gravity to Center , but nothing great , please give me some solution